# Share Datawarehouse based in Big Query with our customers

Tags: google-bigquery

Lets say we have hundreds of bigquery datasets that share the same set of tables and structure. It was done on purpose like that.

The tables inside each dataset consist of a datamart.

We have external customers who want to access their datamarts to extract data.

What tools or options google BigQuery provides to make this a reality?

TIA

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script in your preferred language to grant readonly access to the datasets using the API and IAM permissions. Here's the doc for reference : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam#grant_access_to_a_dataset